# JOIN 3 tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I have 3 tables:

General:

```
all_id |
000001
000002
000003
000004
000005
```

Clients:

```
client_id | client_nmbr
000002    |  22222222
000003    |  33333333
```

Company:

```
company_id | company_nmbr
000001     |  11111111
000004     |  44444444
000005     |  55555555
```

I need to join the 3 tables ordering by all_id and with only one column containing client_nmbr + company_nmbr like this:

```
all_id | all_nmbr
000001 | 11111111
000002 | 22222222
000003 | 33333333
000004 | 44444444
000005 | 55555555
```

I tried using UNION with the tables Clients and Company to get a single column with client_nmbr + company_nmbr. It worked but I can't figure out how to use it with the SELECT to ORDER the column by all_id because it's in the other table.

Here's what I got so far:

```
   SELECT client_nmbr as all_nmbr
   FROM Clients
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT company_nmbr
   FROM Company
```

The result is :

```
all_nmbr|
22222222
33333333
11111111
44444444
55555555
```

I need to JOIN that result with the all_id column and ORDER everything by all_id

Is it possible to do that with only one SELECT query? Any advices?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You write *"with only one column containing client_nmbr + company_nmbr"*, but then show an output with two columns. What should the output look like?

Comment: If every id appears in exactly one of the two tables (clients and company), why do you need to join to the FIRST table? Perhaps the FIRST table also has other columns with additional information? Then - can there be ID's in the first table that can't be found in either "clients" or "company" - and if so, do you need a LEFT join?

Comment: @trincot Actually I need as a result a column with all_id and another one with client_nmbr+company_nmbr and those 2 columns ordered by all_id

Comment: @mathguy That's exactly it. The General table has more information which I need to get too but as I was having problem with clients_nmbr and company_nmbr I thought it wasn't too important. The all_id contains every id in company and client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the other column as the first, and order by the first:

```
SELECT client_id as all_id,
       client_nmbr as all_nmbr
FROM   Clients
UNION ALL 
SELECT company_id,
       company_nmbr
FROM   Company
ORDER BY 1
```

If you do not want the added column in the results, then use a sub query:

```
SELECT all_nmbr
FROM   (
        SELECT client_id as all_id,
               client_nmbr as all_nmbr
        FROM   Clients
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT company_id,
               company_nmbr
        FROM   Company
       )
ORDER BY all_id
```

Although the first table `General` does not seem useful at all (as it can be derived from the other two tables), you could also use that table, and outer join the other two to it:

```
SELECT COALESCE(client_nmbr, company_nmbr) all_nmbr
FROM   General
LEFT JOIN Clients ON client_id = all_id
LEFT JOIN Companies ON company_id = all_id
ORDER BY all_id
```

Comment: Actually the first table (General) has some other columns which I need to select too but as I was having problem only with these I thought I wasn't too important to add that info. Anyways, your answer solved my problem! Thank you so much!